# Update Panel doesn't work inside web part zone

Tags: 2013, web-part, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a visual web part that works if you insert it directly into the page layout, but not when you add it to a web part zone.

The page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPnlArticle" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="navPrev" EventName="click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="navNext" EventName="click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Literal id="litNoResults" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            <asp:Repeater id="repResults" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="current-vacancies-item">
                    <div style="float:right;font-size:10px"><%#((DateTime)Eval("ArticleStartDate")).ToString("d MMM yy")%></div>
                    <p><a href="/Communications/Pages/<%#Eval("FileLeafRef")%>"><%#Eval("ArticleLeadParagraph")%></a></p>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>

            <asp:Literal id="litError" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            <div class="footer">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="navPrev" runat="server" Text="Previous" 
                    onclick="navPrev_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:Literal ID="litNav" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="navNext" runat="server" Text="Next" onclick="navNext_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
            </div>

            <asp:HiddenField ID="hidPageNo" runat="server" Value="0" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadCurrentVacancies();
        }
    }



    private void LoadCurrentVacancies()
    {
        try
        {
            int PageNum = Convert.ToInt32(hidPageNo.Value);

            using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://oursite"))
            {
                using (SPWeb webSite = siteCollection.OpenWeb("OurWeb"))
                {
                    SPList list = webSite.GetList("/theURL");
                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

                    query.Query = "<Where><And><And><And><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Text'>EINewsArticle</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='_Level' /><Value Type='Integer'>1</Value></Eq></And><Leq><FieldRef Name='ArticleStartDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'>#TodayDate#</Value></Leq></And><Gt><FieldRef Name='EIExpiryDate' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>#TodayDate#</Value></Gt></And><Eq><FieldRef Name='EIArticleCategory' /><Value Type='Choice'>Vacancy</Value></Eq></And></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ArticleStartDate' Ascending='False' /><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";
                    string dtToday = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(System.DateTime.Now);

                    query.Query = query.Query.Replace("#TodayDate#", dtToday);

                    SPListItemCollection spColl = list.GetItems(query);

                    if (spColl.Count != 0)
                    {
                        System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
                        table = spColl.GetDataTable();
                        table.AcceptChanges();

                        PagedDataSource objPds = new PagedDataSource();
                        objPds.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
                        objPds.AllowPaging = true;

                        objPds.PageSize = 5;

                        objPds.CurrentPageIndex = PageNum;

                        litNav.Text = "Page: " + (PageNum + 1).ToString() + " of " + objPds.PageCount.ToString();

                        navPrev.Enabled = !objPds.IsFirstPage;
                        navNext.Enabled = !objPds.IsLastPage; 

                        repResults.DataSource = objPds;
                        repResults.DataBind();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        litNoResults.Text = "<div style = 'text-align:center; padding-top:50px; font-size:14px;'>There are no current vacancies</div>";
                        navPrev.Visible = false;
                        navNext.Visible = false;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            litError.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    protected void navPrev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set viewstate variable to the previous page
        int PageNum = Convert.ToInt32(hidPageNo.Value);
        hidPageNo.Value = (PageNum - 1).ToString();

        // Reload control
        LoadCurrentVacancies();
    }

    protected void navNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        litNoResults.Text = "CLick event fired";

        // Set viewstate variable to the next page
        int PageNum = Convert.ToInt32(hidPageNo.Value);
        hidPageNo.Value = (PageNum + 1).ToString();

        // Reload control
        LoadCurrentVacancies();
    }
```

It brings back the list of vacancies as it should. The problem is that the paging controls do not work.

Is there a way to make this work within a web part zone? Do I need to override the webpart OnInit method?